# How could I merge two 30 fps videos into single 60 fps video, using alternating frames from both videos?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two 30fps videos, and I would like to create an output video, in 60fps, where every other frame in the video is alternated between the videos. For example, if I have video `A` and video `B`, the frames of the resulting video would be:

```
A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 ...etc
```

I could recreate this effect by exporting all of the frames from both videos, renaming them, and then compiling them back into a video, but that takes a lot of storage and is very slow. I've also seen questions about doing the opposite thing, turning 60fps into 30fps video, using the mod function to choose every other frame, but haven't seen anything about the opposite.

Comment: Try using [interleave filter](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/interleave_002c-ainterleave.htm.gz). Example: `ffmpeg -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]interleave,setpts=N/60/TB" -r 60 out.mp4`

Comment: That looks to have done the trick! Thanks.